# Sorting in Micronaut (Kotlin)

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, sorting, micronaut

I am working on a Micronaut project using Kotlin, and I'm trying to implement pagination and sorting using `Pagable` interface.

There is `build.gradle`:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.9.0"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen") version "1.9.0"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa") version "1.9.0"
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.0-1.0.13"
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "8.1.1"
    id("io.micronaut.application") version "4.0.2"
    id("io.micronaut.aot") version "4.0.2"
}

version = "0.1"
group = "com.example"

val kotlinVersion = project.properties["kotlinVersion"]
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    ksp("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-processor")
    ksp("io.micronaut.openapi:micronaut-openapi")
    ksp("io.micronaut.serde:micronaut-serde-processor")
    implementation("io.micronaut.serde:micronaut-serde-jackson")

    implementation("io.micronaut.reactor:micronaut-reactor")
    implementation("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-hibernate-reactive")
    implementation("io.micronaut.sql:micronaut-vertx-pg-client")
    implementation("com.ongres.scram:client:2.1")

    implementation("io.micronaut.xml:micronaut-jackson-xml")
    implementation("io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlinVersion}")
    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
    runtimeOnly("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    runtimeOnly("org.yaml:snakeyaml")
}


application {
    mainClass.set("com.example.ApplicationKt")
}
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("17")
}

tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        compilerOptions {
            jvmTarget.set(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.JvmTarget.JVM_17)
        }
    }
    compileTestKotlin {
        compilerOptions {
            jvmTarget.set(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.JvmTarget.JVM_17)
        }
    }
}
graalvmNative.toolchainDetection.set(false)
micronaut {
    runtime("netty")
    testRuntime("junit5")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("com.example.*")
    }
    aot {
        // Please review carefully the optimizations enabled below
        // Check https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-aot/latest/guide/ for more details
        optimizeServiceLoading.set(false)
        convertYamlToJava.set(false)
        precomputeOperations.set(true)
        cacheEnvironment.set(true)
        optimizeClassLoading.set(true)
        deduceEnvironment.set(true)
        optimizeNetty.set(true)
    }
}
```

There is an entity:

```kotlin
@Entity
@Serdeable
@Table(name = "roles")
data class RoleEntity(
        @Id
        @Column(name = "id")
        @JsonProperty("key")
        var roleId: String,

        @Column(name = "description")
        var description: String?
)
```

There is a repository. `AbstractRepository` inheritor of `ReactorPageableRepository` and `ReactorCrudRepository`

```kotlin
@Repository
interface RoleRepository : AbstractRepository<RoleEntity, String> {
    @Query(
        value = "from RoleEntity where lower(roleId) like concat('%', lower(:query), '%') or lower(description) like concat('%', lower(:query), '%')",
        countQuery = "select count(1) from RoleEntity where lower(roleId) like concat('%', lower(:query), '%') or lower(description) like concat('%', lower(:query), '%')"
    )
    override fun findByQuery(query: String, pageable: Pageable): Mono<Page<RoleEntity>>
}
```

Below are the methods that parse the request parameters like `/roles?pageSize=3&sorting[0][field]=description&sorting[0][order]=asc`.

```kotlin
fun getPageable(request: HttpRequest<Any>): Pageable {
    val offset = request.parameters["offset"]?.toInt() ?: 0
    val pageSize = request.parameters["pageSize"]?.toInt() ?: 1
    val sorting = parseSorting(request)
    return Pageable.from(offset / pageSize, pageSize, sorting)
}

private fun parseSorting(request: HttpRequest<Any>): Sort {
    val sorting = mutableListOf<Sort.Order>()
    while (request.parameters["sorting[${sorting.count()}][field]"] != null) sorting.add(
        Sort.Order(
            request.parameters["sorting[${sorting.count()}][field]"],
            Sort.Order.Direction.valueOf(request.parameters["sorting[${sorting.count()}][order]"].uppercase()),
            true
        )
    )
    return Sort.of(sorting)
}
```

The result of the functions for query from example is: `Pageable(max=3, number=0, sort=DefaultSort(orderBy=[property = "description", direction = {Sort$Order$Direction@15418} "ASC", ignoreCase = true]))`. However, when passing this object to a `RoleRepository.findByQuery()` I catch an exception: `org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Could not interpret path expression 'roleEntity_.description'`.

If I passing a non-existent field in the request parameters, I catch a different exception: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot sort on non-existent property path: desc`.

What am I missing? Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Did you create `AbstractRepository` by yourself? If so, can you provide the code?